# sql server media not supported x64 system

Tags: sql-server

My home computer has windows 7 ultimate x86. I downloanded and attempted to start sql server 2012  for X86 OS,but they all gave  the "sql server media not supported x64 system.To continue,run the SQL server setup media that matches your system"error when i attempted to run the setup file

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your running it off a `.iso` file, and your computer meets the [minimum requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx). If so, mount the `.iso` in your local drive, and try to run it from there.

Comment: My computer meet the minimum requirements and i run .exe